# How to split the file lines using particular delimiter and show in particular orientation format in shell script not using awk

Tags: arrays, shell, sed, grep, orientation

**Input File : input.txt**

```
<UndefineProperty name="admin.admin.adapters"/>--><!--<AddToProperty 
name="admin.admin.adapters"
value="abc^abc.xz=abc"/>--><Property name="admin.admin.adapters" ride="true"
         targetFile="file/path/file.txt"
         value="abc,xz=abc,xz=com^abc.com.xz=abc,ac=com"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file/path/file.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file1.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file2.xconf"/>
<Property name="ac.abc.Password" ride="true"
         targetFile="file/path/abc.properties"
         value="ac.abc.encryptedPassword"/>
<Property name="ac.pqr.Protocol" ride="true"
         targetFile="file/pqr.properties"
         value="https"/>
```

**Output :**

```
<UndefineProperty name="admin.admin.adapters"/>-->
<!--<AddToProperty name="admin.admin.adapters" value="abc^abc.xz=abc"/>-->
<Property name="admin.admin.adapters" ride="true" targetFile="file/path/file.txt" value="abc,xz=abc,xz=com^abc.com.xz=abc,ac=com"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file/path/file.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file1.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file2.xconf"/>
<Property name="ac.abc.Password" ride="true" targetFile="file/path/abc.properties" value="ac.abc.encryptedPassword"/>
<Property name="ac.pqr.Protocol" ride="true" targetFile="file/pqr.properties" value="https"/>
```

**Tried :**

```
delimiter="<"
newarray=()

while read -r line ; 
do
  newarray+=( "${line%%"$delimiter"*}" )
  line=${delimiter}${line#*"$delimiter"}
  echo ${line} >> input.txt1
done < input.txt
```

**Note :** Above code isn't working as expected.
It shows just output which  contain this (<) delimiter and orientation also not done in above code.

Comment: POSIX shells do not have arrays. Which specific shell are you trying to use? bash?

Comment: Yeah, I am using bash

Comment: should `<a b="c < < < < <            "/>` be changed or output as-is?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, As i mentioned in output section, need in that format so the data between these two delimiter <....../> should be in one single line with paticular space.

Comment: `sed -e ':loop; /[^>]$/{N; b loop}; s/\n */ /g; s/></>\n</g' INPUTFILE` (not using `AWK` 
 :-3 )

Comment: my example contains those delimiters and multiple spaces. Should every `<` start a new line? How many lines should this become: `<a b="c < < <     "/><!-- <e f=" /> /> />"/>-->` ?

Comment: How many lines here? `<a b="/> <"/>`

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/mbD3MTcHq <-- Thanks for this much, now i can see orientation but still new line between <.../> these.

Comment: How many lines here? <a b="/> <"/> <--  Atleast 500 lines, but its expandable cant say exact count

Comment: @Shr I think you misunderstood @jhnc comment. In the case you have `<a b="/> <"/>` do you consider that it will not split into two line because `"/> <"` is considered a string or do you consider that it will split into two line `<a b="/>` & `<"/>`  ?

Comment: Hope do you got the pattern?

Comment: @jhnc we just have this case <property=.....  ride=.... targetFile=.... value=.../> all lines should be in this type of or similar kind of format may be one or two sometime missing in particular close.

Comment: Your description of `< ... />` in a single line doesn't match your output, as there are some `< ... />-->`.

Comment: @Grobu It looks good, but still not in one line. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: @Shr you get one `<...>` tag per line, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Thats what I wanted <....> in one line, when  I tried above sed command its not working for 200+ lines. When i ran above one two times then only its showing in one line but not case for 200+ lines.

Comment: Perhaps there are lines ending in `...>(one or more spaces)`? If you try `sed -e ':loop; /[^> ] *$/{N; b loop}; s/\n */ /g; s/></>\n</g' INPUTFILE`, is it any better?

Comment: sed -e ':loop; /[^> ]\n*$/{N; b loop}; s/\n */ /g; s/></>\n</g' -i INPUTFILE added \n ... looks fine now. Thanks alot Grobu.

Comment: Why not using awk specifically? Are there any other mandatory POSIX tools you can't use such as sed or grep? Can you use tools that are designed to parse XML such as xmlstarlet?  By the way, you should read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably parse XML with a simple sed or bash program.

This bash script produces the sample output provided in the question from the sample input provided in the question:

```
(
    set extglob
    v=
    while read -r r; do v+=${v:+ }$r; done <input.txt
    echo "${v//>?( )</>$'\n'<}" >input.txt1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed for `-E` and `-z`, this will produce the expected output from the posted sample input (YMMV with different input of course):

```
$ sed -Ez 's/\n\s+/ /g; s/\n(.)/\1/g; s/></>\n</g' input.txt
<UndefineProperty name="admin.admin.adapters"/>-->
<!--<AddToProperty name="admin.admin.adapters"value="abc^abc.xz=abc"/>-->
<Property name="admin.admin.adapters" ride="true" targetFile="file/path/file.txt" value="abc,xz=abc,xz=com^abc.com.xz=abc,ac=com"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file/path/file.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file1.xconf"/>
<ConfigurationRef xlink:href="file2.xconf"/>
<Property name="ac.abc.Password" ride="true" targetFile="file/path/abc.properties" value="ac.abc.encryptedPassword"/>
<Property name="ac.pqr.Protocol" ride="true" targetFile="file/pqr.properties" value="https"/>
```